# How does Google SignIn SDK (OAuth) redirect back to iOS app?

Tags: ios, google-oauth, sfsafariviewcontroller

I press Sign In. It opens `SFSafariViewController`, does the login and then comes back to the app after. Does it call the redirect URI like `myapp://` at the end, because I setup the client ID?

Or is there a `window.close` javascript happening somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

It will redirect to your app using the callback URL you provided.
You can simply cross-check it by setting a breakpoint in the AppDelegate method `open(_:options:completionHandler:)`